# Factoring common number in logs.

Tags: logarithms

I need to find the value of 'x' in the equation  $8^x + 2^x = 130$.

As you can see, my final answer at the bottom of the pic is different from what my calculator is saying.

I feel that the step in line 3, which says,  $ log (8^x) + log (2^x) = log (130) $ might have something to do with the wrong answer.

Can someone give me feedback on what I worked out?

[image]

Comment: You don't have $\log(a+b) = \log ( a) + \log (b)$ but $\log(ab) = \log ( a) + \log (b)$. Try writing $8$ as a power of $2$

Comment: $\log(a+b)\neq \log(a) + \log(b)$

Comment: Yes, you can "do the same thing to both sides" and have any solutions to the original also be solutions for the modified... but recall that if you are doing something to a side, you are doing it to *the entire side* as though that entire side were in parentheses.  Yes, if $a=c$ then you have $f(a)=f(c)$.  If you have $(a+b)=c$ then $f(a+b)=f(c)$.  Most of the time we do *not* have that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, including taking logarithms.

Comment: @Eric Where do you see me using log(a+b) = log(a) + log(b)?

Comment: "*Where do you see me using log(a+b) = log(a) = log(b)?*"  When you "took the log of both sides" and called this the sum of logs on the left rather than a single log on the left.

Comment: @JMoravitz So are you saying that  'doing the same thing to both sides' does -not- apply in line 3?

Comment: "Taking the log of both sides" should have taken you from $8^x+2^x=13$ to $\log(8^x+2^x) = \log(13)$.  Compare to taking the log of both sides of $c=13$, but where $c$ happens to be $8^x+2^x$.  You would have $\log(c)=\log(13)$, and then replacing what $c$ happens to be when written the other way.

Comment: @JMoravitz Aha! Got it! So my line 3 should have said, log ( 8^x + 2^x ) = log 130.

Comment: You know that $12+13=25$... well consider the action of "*adding one*" and let's call that function $s$ (*s for "successor"*).  If we were to want to "add one to both sides" this is not $s(12)+s(13)=s(25)$ which would have been $(12+1) + (13+1) = (25+1)$ which you can see is wrong since $27\neq 26$, but rather it is $(12+13)+1 = (25) +1$

Comment: One way is to let $y=2^x$ and solve the cubic $y^3+y-130=0$.

Comment: @IraeVid I used your method. Great trick, when we convert everything into a equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 3 should have said, $\log ( 8^x + 2^x ) = \log 130$.

It will also help to assume $y = 2^x$.

Then proceed to find the value of $y$, in the equation $y^3 + y -130 = 0$.

Comment: Although it may be hard to proceed from here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @paw88789 Not that hard ;-)

Comment: @Community This answer is very clear and needs no "additional details".